# Is it possible to test a Model that acts_as_tree

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing

How can I test a model that `acts_as_tree` in a unit test?

Comment: acts_as_tree is already tested. Perhaps you want to test if acts_as_tree has been called?

Comment: It makes sense to test a few key points of the interface, I think.  Consider what happens if someone overrides one of the methods to do some extra work and breaks the contract?  I wouldn't spend a lot of time on it, but it's not entirely worthless.

Comment: @leethal: yes i just wanted to test if acts_as_tree has been called. i think i just have to create some parents and some childs and then traverse them !!

Answer (score 0):

You could initialize it with some random values and see if traversing it [in several different ways](http://www.niksula.cs.hut.fi/~trakla/book/english/node4.html) (such as preorder, postorder, inorder and level order) produces the same result.